# Função que retorna valor de uma URL

Tags: javascript

Como eu transformaria esta função para que ao invés dela enviar o valor de data para prepareListDados() quando for chamada, ela retornasse esse valor de data quando fosse chamada em prepareListDados()

```
const getDados = async () => {
  let url = 'http://' + host + '/dados';
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
          var data = xhttp.responseText;
          prepareListDados(data);
      }
  }
  await xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  await xhttp.send();
}
```

como por exemplo:

```
const prepareListDados = () =>{
let dados = getDados();
}
```

assim o valor de data estaria na minha variável dados na função prepareListDados();

edit1:

```
const getDadosAsync = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let url = 'http://' + host + '/dados';
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      var data = xhttp.responseText;
      resolve(data);
    }
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
});

const prepareListDados = async () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let dados = await getDadosAsync();
    resolve(dados)
});

const setList = async () => {
 let dados = await prepareListDados();
}
```

algo assim

Comment: Você quer transformar uma operação assíncrona em síncrona, não dá.

Comment: e qual solução me daria para receber dados de uma url em uma função síncrona?

Comment: No browser? A recomendação é nunca buscar dados de forma síncrona, pois isso trava a página até que a resposta seja recebida.

Answer (score 1):

Retorne uma `Promise`, e chame o `resolve` da promise no valor deferido, que será obtido quando você utilizar `await`.

```
const getDadosAsync = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let url = 'http://' + host + '/dados';
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      var data = xhttp.responseText;
      resolve(data);
    }
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
})

const prepareListDadosAsync = async () => {
  let dados = await getDadosAsync();
}
```

Uma maneira ainda mais fácil de fazer isso é utilizando `fetch`, que já retorna uma promises por padrão:

```
const getDadosAsync = async () => {
  let response = await fetch('http://' + host + '/dados');
  return await response.text();
}

const prepareListDadosAsync = async () => {
  let dados = await getDadosAsync();
}
```

Comment: Boa, eu ia sugerir que você desse um exemplo com fetch. Já que é pra usar async/await, certamente faz mais sentido (inclusive por ambos terem os mesmos problemas de compatibilidade).

Comment: Funcou exatamente como previsto, obrigado! mas uma curiosidade agora, tem como fazer uma cadeia dessas promise? tipo no exemplo: se a prepareListDadosAsync = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => ... daria certo? e assim sucessivamente

Comment: @VitorPereira, não entendi muito bem a dúvida. Seria melhor editar a pergunta ou então criar uma nova com todos os detalhes do que você quer.

Comment: @user140828 Olha o edit1, algo parecido com aquilo